# Shopify Webhook Real Time changing

Tags: node.js, shopify, shopify-app

is there an api on shopify where I can see real time when data changes ? Maybe I have a node server and I use sockets to see when anyone has bought anything from my shop that I get a notification via nodejs on my backend. is it possible ? a few websites has this, they offers you to sell on their site and you can see real time changes data when anything was bought

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can [subscribe to multiple Webhooks](https://shopify.dev/apps/webhooks/configuration/https) to get notified when a change occurs on your shop. Using the REST Admin API, available [webhook event topics](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2023-01/resources/webhook#event-topics) include:

- `orders/create`: occurs whenever an order is created / someone buys from your shop.
- `orders/paid`: occurs whenever an order is paid.
- `orders/fulfilled`: occurs whenever an order is fulfilled.
- `orders/cancelled`: occurs whenever an order is cancelled.

Use the [`/admin/api/2023-01/webhooks.json`](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-rest/2023-01/resources/webhook#post-webhooks) endpoint to subscribe to a webhook:

```
// Node.js - Session is built by the OAuth process
const webhook = new shopify.rest.Webhook({session: session});
webhook.topic = "orders/create";
webhook.address = "https://example.hostname.com/";
// format you want to receive the event data in 
webhook.format = "json"; // or XML
// fields you want to receive
webhook.fields = [
  "id",
  "note"
];
await webhook.save({
  update: true,
});
```

You can also use the [GraphQL Admin API](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2023-01/enums/WebhookSubscriptionTopic) for the same purpose.